# How do I add each filename from images in dir (look at code)

Tags: c#, image, path, label

I want to show all the images that is inside debug dir. Also the filename as label.

My only problem is showing filename from the path of each image. It load only 1 filename

```
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(@"images");
        foreach (string image in images)
        {
            PictureBox PB = new PictureBox();
            PB.Image = new Bitmap(image);
            PB.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
            PB.Size = new Size(250, 180);
            PB.Location = new Point(x, y);
            panel1.Controls.Add(PB);
            x += 260;
        }
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;

        string names = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(@"images");
        foreach (string name in names)
        {
            Label label1 = new Label();
            label1.Text = name;
            label1.Location = new Point(a, b);
            this.Controls.Add(label1);
            a += 20;
        }
```

Comment: Can we buy a hint?  How does it fail and which line is LXII?

Comment: `System.IO.Path.GetFileName()` returns a string representing the filename and extension in a path, not a collection of file names

Comment: You can't foreach a string from a string, I think you need to change that loop, or just include in the first loop

Comment: It fails trying to get the filename from my images in my dir in debug. so

Comment: Include in first loop would be best but cant seem to get it working

Comment: Only shows first filename in dir

Comment: The second loop only executes once and it returns only 1 name, because you ask it for GetFileName, which doesn't return a list or array, but a single string.  The foreach attempts to enumerate the string type and it returns 1 entry, because there is only one entry to return.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx

Comment: @TheGreatCO, You cannot loop a string from a string at all, this loop won't even compile

Comment: @sa_ddam213, Actually string is IEnumerable<char> so you'll get a bunch of letters from that loop.  I try to point out why code won't work, instead of just giving people answers. It helps in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(@"images");
    foreach (string image in images)
    {
        PictureBox PB = new PictureBox();
        PB.Image = new Bitmap(image);
        PB.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
        PB.Size = new Size(250, 180);
        PB.Location = new Point(x, y);
        panel1.Controls.Add(PB);
        x += 260;

        Label label1 = new Label();
        label1.Text = Path.GetFileName(name);
        label1.Location = new Point(a, b);
        this.Controls.Add(label1);
        a += 20;
    }

}
```

Comment: Im trying to show the filename as a label on all images in dir
The filename needs to be over picture do i need to make a container?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need 2 loops, you could just grab the filename and create the label in the first loop,

Something like:

```
int x = 0;
string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\StackOverflow\New Folder");
foreach (string image in images)
{
    Panel item = new Panel();
    item.AutoSize = true;
    item.Location = new Point(x, 0);


    PictureBox PB = new PictureBox();
    PB.Image = new Bitmap(image);
    PB.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
    PB.Size = new Size(250, 180);

    Label label1 = new Label();
    label1.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(image);
    label1.Location = new Point(0, 90);
    label1.Width = 250;
    label1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

    item.Controls.Add(label1);
    item.Controls.Add(PB);

    panel1.Controls.Add(item);
    x += 260;

}
```

Result[image]

Comment: Its says: Use of unassigned local  variable x, y, a, b

Comment: tried what you did, the images are still showing but not the labels

Comment: is you `Panel` ontop of the `Labels`? because you are adding the `Images` to a `Panel` but the `Labels` to the `Window`, do you want the `Label` with the `Image`??

Comment: Its because all the labels are ontop of each other but 20pixels to the left, What layout are you tring to achive??

Comment: Im trying to show the filename as a label on all images in dir

Comment: The filename needs to be over picture do i need to make a container?

Comment: Yes adding a container is probably the best option, I have updated my answer with an example

Comment: @user2060000 glad you got it working, its helpful to accept answers that solve your problem so others dont spend time troubleshooting. Please see [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)